# Tensorflow-datasets "plant_village" dataset no examples were yield

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

My Environment:

Python 3.11.2, Tensorflow 2.12.0-rc1, Tensorflow-datasets 4.8.3, perfect clean newly created virtual environment in Visual Studio Code with the only operations performed being pip install the two libraries above .

The import statements :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
```

runs quickly without bugs. However, the next line:

```
dataset, info = tfds.load('plant_village', split='train', with_info=True)
```

yields the error:

[image]

Attempts made to access other datasets, like mnist, are successful. Is this a bug specific to this data set? How do I overcome this bug and load this dataset? Note that exactly the same lines of code work perfectly on google colab .

Comment: In Python 3.9.16 it ran for like 10 minutes but did yield the dataset and info, which means it could be due to your Python version... though I'm not sure what to suggest to resolve the issue (besides using another version). Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

As per the tested [build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu), you should install the stable tensorflow with the given compatible python version in your system to avoid unexpected errors.

`TensorFlow 2.11` and `python 3.10` are the latest stable compatible versions.

There is no tensorflow version available compatible with the `python 3.11` version as of now.

[image]

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @TFer2 mentioned, Google Colab currently uses **Tensorflow 2.11.0**, **Tensorflow Datasets 4.8.3** and **Python 3.9.16** at the time of writing this comment. You should verify the version number of these libraries in the Colab you were using and create a new environment to match these versions.